# Fortify email verification only works when verification link is pasted in tab where user is logged in

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, fortify

I'm using quite a completely vanilla Fortify setup, sending email verification links is working with mailtrap. However, when I click the link in the mail, it opens the app and makes the user login, after which it doesn't redirect back to the verification url, but just shows the homescreen that tells the user to verify their mail.

The only way the verification link **does** work is when you paste the link in a tab where the user is already logged in. At first glance, to me it seems like a browser issue, that the browser doesn't preserve the cookies, but I've tried with different browsers (Safari, Chrome and Firefox) and all have the same issue. I run the laravel app locally through valet (or expose when I need to test API calls from a third party service) and dev environment on ubuntu 20.04, both have the same issue.